# Is this new method to find primes?

Tags: distribution-of-primes

By observation I found this method which can be proofed easily ,but not sure if it is mentioned somewhere before and that's what almost should be.

This is the method:

For every $p_n$ & $a$ that satisfy $p_n < p_n\#-a < p_{n+1}^2$

If $(a)$ is a prime then $(p_n\#-a)$ is also a prime

and if $(p_n\#-a)$ is a prime then $(a)$ is possible a prime

Example:

a=2213 (prime number)

let $p_n$ any prime satisfy the above

for instance $p_5=11$ then $p_5\#=2310$

$11<2310-2213<13*13$

$11<97<169$ it's OK

Then 97 must be a prime

...
EDIT:
...

The Proof

Firstly I miss the condition of $(a)$ which should always greater than $p_n$ $(a > p_n)$ as will be mentioned in the following proof:

$(a)$ and $(p_n\#-a)$ are symmetrical around $\frac {p_n\#}{2}$

Let $a=\frac {p_n\#}{2}+b$ then $(p_n\#-a)=\frac {p_n\#}{2}-b$

$p_n\#=(\frac {p_n\#}{2}+b)+(\frac {p_n\#}{2}-b)$

assume that $(\frac {p_n\#}{2}+b)$ is divisible by $\{p_k : p_k \le p_n\}$

then $(\frac {p_n\#}{2}-b)$ must be divisible by $p_k$ too

because $\frac {p_n\#}{2}$ is always divisible by any prime $2 < p_k \le p_n$
 so if $(+b)$ is divisible by $p_k$ then $(-b)$ is divisible as well.

and if $(\frac {p_n\#}{2}+b)$ is not divisible by any prime of $\{p_k : p_k \le p_n\}$ then $(\frac {p_n\#}{2}-b)$ should be also not divisible by the same prime.

So we have this range which we can define the symmetry of the numbers that are not divisible by $\{p_k : p_k \le p_n\}$. that range is from $(p_n+1)$ to $(p_n\#-(p_n+1))$ then $a$ should always greater than $p_n$ $(a > p_n)$

but unfortunately this range of symmetry is broken by the primes greater than $p_n$ because $p_n\#$ is not divisible by $p_{n+1}$ and greater.

So the limits of symmetry ,which can not be affected by the primes greater than $p_n$ , can be defined between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}^2$

So if $(p_n\#-a)$ satisfy $p_n \lt p_n\#-a \lt p_{n+1}^2$ then it is in the range of symmetry and if $(a)$ is prime then $(p_n\#-a)$ is also prime

but if $(p_n\#-a)$ is prime then $(a)$ could be prime because it will not be divisible by $\{ p_k : p_k \le p_n\}$ but on the other hand it could be divisible by the primes greater than $p_n$ because it is may located out of the range where the symmetry is broken.

My question is:

I need to varify this proof numerically for large numbers and check if it is correct for large prime numbers

We can notice the symmetry in these examples

1) For $p_3\#=2*3*5=30$

$p_{n+1}^2=7∗7=49$

so all the primes $5 < p < 30$ are symmetrical around 15

$\frac {p_n\#}{2}=15$ note that $15±2 , 15±4 , 15±8$ are all primes.

2) For $p_4=210$

$p_{n+1}^2=11∗11=121$, number $121$ is less than $210$ which will break the symmetry starting from $121$

so the range that will maintain the symmetry is $(7 < 210-a < 121)$ , $a > 7$

$\frac {p_n\#}{2}=105$ note that $105±2 , 105±4 , 105±8$ are primes etc...

Let $a=151$ (prime number) then $210-151=59$

$7 < 59 < 121$ then $59$ is a prime.

Comment: So how exactly did you find $97$ using $11$ (or using $2213$)?

Comment: What do you denote with $\#$ ?

Comment: Dear @fleablood I think its a rude way of asking about notations!

Comment: @fleablood No need to swear. It's a well known notation for primorial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Comment: Okay, it is a way of finding primes but requires you to know large prime numbers first before finding smaller prime numbers.

Comment: You might be interested, Pentapolis, in a paper called Primes at a glance, http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3.pdf

Comment: @fleablood: If it is indeed a way of finding primes, then the fact that it requires you to know large prime numbers first before finding smaller prime numbers does not necessarily make it useless. For example, consider the fact that the largest known prime number record is typically of the form $2^n-1$, and that many primes smaller than this value are left unknown. That being said, I still haven't figured out OP's method (for finding a prime using some other prime) to begin with, and I sincerely doubt that such method is provided in this post.

Comment: It sounds like a variation of the Fortunate numbers conjecture: for a given positive integer $n$ the Fortunate number is the smallest integer $a \gt 1$ such that $p_n \# + a$ is a prime number, where the primorial $p_n \#$ is the product of the first $n$ prime numbers. The conjecture states that $a$ is always $1$ or prime. But it this case the OP is using $p_n \# - a$ instead of $p_n \# + a$. And somehow there is an interval associated to the primorial that is able to catch a prime $a$ and a prime $p_n\#-a$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number

Comment: Yes, using this method to find big primes by entering small primes is actually not always give precise results, but for the vice versa it works 100% for all the numbers I tested.

Answer (score 3):

Your first test is false: $n=3$ and $a=2$. Then $p_n = 5$, $p_n \# - 2 = 28$ is obviously composite, but $2$ is prime.

---

For your second test: as you say, $p_n \# - a$ being prime doesn't necessarily mean $a$ is prime: see $n=4, a=121$, where $p_n \# - a = 89$ is prime (and less than $p_5^2 = 121$) but $a = 121 = 11^2$ is not.
So that part doesn't constitute a reliable way of finding primes, and I can't see that it can be easily improved.

---

I originally wrote the following about Part 1, before finding that counterexample.

For your first test, this is a way of finding primes. I'm going to go by contradiction, I'm afraid, though it's aesthetically displeasing.

Suppose $p_n \# - a$ were composite; then it would be divisible by some prime $p$.
But because $a$ is prime, we must have either $p > p_n$ or $p=a$.
So the only primes that divide $p_n \# - a$ are $a$ or things bigger than $p_n$.

If $p_n \# - a$ were divisible by two primes (counting multiplicity) bigger than $p_n$, then your second condition would fail: $p_n \# - a < p_{n+1}^2$ would be false.
So the prime factorisation of $p_n \# - a$ is "at most one prime bigger than $p_n$, and some number of copies of $a$".

- If $a > p_n$, then $a$ can't appear in the prime factorisation at all, because $a \not \mid p_n \#$ so $a \not \mid p_n \# - a$.
  That means the prime factorisation is just "some single prime bigger than $p_n$", contradicting compositeness of $p_n \# - a$.

So $a = p_i$ for some $i$, and $$p_n \# - a = p_k^{\epsilon} \times a^r$$ for some $k > n$ and some $r \geq 0$, where $\epsilon$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I think you can modifiy the restrictions to $p_n < p_n\#-a < p_{n}^2$ to make it work. But nice catch.

Comment: I miss the condition of $a > p_n$ for all $a$ values, then in your first test $a$ must be greater than $5$ , so if you don't mind read the proof in the EDIT carefully and post your feedback